# Is it valid to use 'cruzar' to indicate turning? Shouldn't it be 'girar'?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos, definiciones, colombia, venezuela

My computer based Spanish course just served up a lesson where they translated `cruzar` to mean `to turn` when giving directions (and did so on multiple occasions).
This confused me as I understood `cruzar` to mean `to cross`, and expected `girar` to be used for turning.  And two online dictionaries and my paper dictionary do not seem to mention any usage of `cruzar` have anything to do with turning.

Yet when I went to google, it translated both

> usted debe **cruzar** a la derecha

and

> usted debe **girar** a la derecha

as the same thing:

> You should **turn** right

What am I missing in the use of `cruzar` overlapping `girar`?

In my language course continues to use `cruzar` as `to turn`.  The following is some dialog from the lesson I am doing now:

> (...) y luego vas a **cruzar** a la derecha (...) En la calle treinta **cruzas** a la derecha y caminas media cuadra

and their translation:

> (...) And then you're going to turn right (...) In street Thirty you'll turn right and walk half a block.

I did what I should have done and went to the website of my language course, where someone else has asked the exact same question.  There was a comment that indicated:

> this verb seems to be only used to say "to turn" in some parts of
>   Colombia, and in Venezuela

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: That is interesting.  The *Diccionario de americanismos* doesn't have this usage and they have a lot of regional meanings for *cruzar*.  They really ought to change the course to use *girar* or *doblar* which are the two most common terms.

Comment: @guifa I agree with you, but on the commercial side of things I'd say it is impractical ($$$) for them do this  at this time (it's multiple voice actors, DVD production and everything).  Interestingly the main teacher for the spanish course is apparently from Venezuela - so that may explain the bias, but not excuse not using the most common forms.

Comment: I would just keep going use what they want you to use, but know that there are other words that are far more common.  It's true that sometimes the word choices in books can be a bit odd (every book has a questionable choice or two), but sometimes it's best for students if they choose one word and stick with it whatever it is (while perhaps mentioning in a footnote major regional variations).  Consider a word like "computer" that can be either *el computador*, *la computadora* or *el ordenador*.  It'll confuse students if it uses all three early on.

Comment: @guifa I am forced to continue the way they want, otherwise I'd never complete the exercises correctly.  However I have a lot of history with the common use of `cruzar` prior to this course - so I am more irked now!

Answer (score 3):

Quizá sea una fusión de: «En el siguiente cruce gire a la derecha». O una manera resumida de decir «cruzar situándose en el lado derecho».

Estas dos palabras (cruzar, girar) significan principalmente lo que has dicho. Yo no creo haber oído la expresión «cruzar a la derecha», pero, si realmente se usa, si no se trata de lo que te he dicho en el primer párrafo -algo entendible por el contexto-, creo que no te estás perdiendo nada.

Comment: Mi clase de español se sigue utilizando `cruzar` para `girar`. Mire mi nuevo ejemplo. No entiendo por qué!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct because I learned that `cruzar` means to cross and `girar` means to turn. I also checked on google translate and wrote "You should cross right" and it translated saying "usted debe cruzar a la derecha". Then I wrote "You should turn right" and translated saying "usted debe girar a la derecha".

Example:

> El mapa me dio instrucciones y me dijo que girar a la izquierda

In English is saying:The map gave me directions and told me to turn left.

> El mapa me dio instrucciones y me dijo que cruzar la calle

In English is saying: The map gave me directions and told me to cross the street

Comment: Good answer, but instead of "girar" and "cruzar" you should have used "girara" or "girase" (same with cruzar).

Comment: @Diego why is this the case?

Comment: @TAbraham, because right now it means something closer to "You should to cross right; You should to turn right". You don't want to use the **infinitive** form there, you want to decline it to convey that you _were told or suggested_ to perform an action, and the subjunctive mood introduces that inflection. You are welcome to post a question about it if is still unclear. Probably you will get a better explanation of which tenses can or should be used and why (a comment can be very limiting!).

Comment: While I agree with you it doesn't seem to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que se refiere a girar cuando no vas a tener que pasar por encima de la carretera (no "cruzas" nada), es decir, vas por la acera de la derecha y giras a la derecha continuando por la misma acera.

Sin embargo si vas por la acera de la izquierda y quieres ir a la derecha debes cruzar la carretera, luego no sonaría mal decir "cruza a la derecha".

Comment: La razón de mi explicación anterior es que una frase muy utilizada es "cruza la carretera".

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo. Entonces, dado que en la cultura latina manejamos por la derecha, habría que pensar que solo es posible "cruzar" si estamos girando a la izquierda.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh.  I tried six online dictionaries and none of them included this expression.  Yet, when I google the exact phrase `cruzar a la derecha` I get tons of hits, authentic articles.

Here's just one example from *[El Tiempo](https://www.eltiempo.com/archivo/documento/MAM-3065133)* (Columbia):

> Varios lectores de Vehículos escribieron a esta redacción preguntando si hacer el cruce a la derecha mientras la luz del semáforo está en rojo es una acción prohibida

It seems that at least in Columbia this is a reasonable way to talk.

I noticed that one of the dictionary definitions speaks of a farmer plowing in a criss-cross pattern.  This gave me the idea that whenever there's a concept of perpendicularity, *cruzar* can be used.  Well, when you turn right, you are making a 90 degree angle (perpendicular).  Hopefully this connection will make the phrase feel more comfortable for you.